# null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.collections.List<com.android.billingclient.api.Purchase>

Tags: android, kotlin, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

Most of my app users don't experience any crashes. However, some of my app users are getting this fatal exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.collections.List<com.android.billingclient.api.Purchase>
       at com.company.appname.ActivityClass$loadAllSKUs$1.onSkuDetailsResponse(ActivityClass.java:10)
       at com.android.billingclient.api.zzj.run(zzj.java:7)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7178)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:503)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:942)
```

Here is my code. I use it to see if a user has already bought an in-app purchase. If he didn't, launch the billing flow.

```
  private lateinit var billingClient: BillingClient
  private val skuList = listOf("product")
  private boolean isOwned = false

  private fun loadAllSKUs() {
    if (billingClient.isReady)
    {
      val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
              .setSkusList(skuList)
              .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
              .build()
      billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params) { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->
        if (skuDetailsList != null)
        {
          if (billingResult.responseCode === BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && !skuDetailsList.isEmpty())
          {
            for (skuDetailsObject in skuDetailsList)
            {
              val skuDetails = skuDetailsObject
              if (skuDetails.sku.equals("product"))
              {
                val result: Purchase.PurchasesResult = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
                val purchases: List<Purchase> = result.getPurchasesList() as List<Purchase>

                for (purchase in purchases)
                {
                  val thisSKU = purchase.sku
                  if (thisSKU == "product")
                  {
                    isOwned = true;
                    // System.out.println("OWNED")
                  }
                }
               


if(isOwned == false){
                    val billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams
                            .newBuilder()
                            .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                            .build()
                    billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this@ActivityClass, billingFlowParams)
}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Please tell me how to fix this, thanks. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55976378/getpurchaseslist-null-pointer-exception) gets the same error but a fix has not been found apparently.

Comment: `result.getPurchasesList()` is null and you are casting it to non null type `List<Purchase>` which is causing the issue

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi I understand. But, why is this happening on some devices and not all of them? And how can I fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: "why is this happening on some devices and not all of them" can't be answered without knowing the API you are dealing with. "how can I fix this issue?" This depends on: 1. Why are you casting (`as List<Purchase>`) in the first place? 2. what do you want to do if you get `null` there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kotlin is a lot more expressive than a lot of cascading if...

Also, Kollin handles nullity at compile time so IDE should notify you if is null or not.

I tried to rewrite your code because is very undebuggable.
I honestly don't know if it works and if it does the same things (it should but as i saidall those if are difficult to understand) but I find it more readable and debuggable.

Remember that in order to remove all if !=null you can use ?. operator

Hope it helps you to understand Kotlin expressivity

```
private fun loadAllSKUs() {
    billingClient.takeIf{it.isReady}
    ?.let {
    val params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()
            .setSkusList(skuList)
            .setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
            .build()
    billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params) { billingResult, skuDetailsList ->
    skuDetailsList
        ?.takeIf{ billingResult.responseCode === BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && skuDetailsList.isNotEmpty() }
        ?.filter {it.sku.equals("product")}
        ?.forEach { skuDetails -> 
            val result: Purchase.PurchasesResult = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP)
            val purchases: List<Purchase>? = result.getPurchasesList() as? List<Purchase>
            val isOwned = purchases?.any { it.sku == "product" }?:false
            
            if(!isOwned){
                val billingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams
                        .newBuilder()
                        .setSkuDetails(skuDetails)
                        .build()
                billingClient.launchBillingFlow(skuDetails@ActivityClass, billingFlowParams)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The code is neater but I don't think it solves the issue I'm encountering on some devices.

Comment: A comment said that it's because `result.getPurchasesList()` is null and I'm casting it to non null type `List<Purchase>`

Comment: Also, I get `Unresolved reference: it` in the 2nd line

Comment: I've edited the snippet with a cast to null for List<Purchase>

I think you should look into Kotlin lang reference https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/

Answer (score 1):

As it was said, the error points to the forced cast of `result.getPurchasesList()`

You need to check for that case and capture more data on what it returns and why, when your application is in that state.

As for the answer above and the error on  `Unresolved reference: it`, to use takeIf you must pass a predicate so you have to change those parentheses to {}

```
    billingClient.takeIf{it.isReady}?.let {
```

Check https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/using-kotlin-takeif-or-takeunless-c9eeb7099c22

Comment: Do you think the answer above solves the `result.getPurchasesList()` error?

Comment: yes sorry, I've edited the code manually and I didn't notice :D